# Spark version 1.4.1 instead of 1.5.2 HdInsight

Tags: linux, azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

I've set up an Azure HdInsight Linux Spark Cluster which should come with the 1.5.2 version of Spark. However, if I try to output the version number by using sparkContext.version I keep getting 1.4.1.

Is there maybe a step I'm missing with the configuration? I've been booting up clusters both through the GUI and through scripts.

Comment: I don't think this question is off-topic. Azure HDInsight is a tool that programmers use. (I don't, so I have no idea about the Spark version there. Even 1.5.2 is pretty old.)

Comment: I have the same issue, the version in Azure says 1.5.2, but once it's actually booted sc.version gives me 1.4.1.
In the meantime, I switched to AWS EMR, which runs on 1.6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug on our side.  The binary version is actually 1.5.2 but it is being reported incorrectly.

Comment: Indeed, this appears to be the case. Also, it seems that the problem was solved in the last few days. Many thanks!